# PasteAndFormat from Word to Outlook causes error 5097

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, office365

I'm thinking this could be a software issue as the code was working for years, up until last week. Nevertheless, without admin rights, I can't do much aside from workarounds.

I have a program that generates a template, which is sent to Outlook for mailing. Since last week, a line of code started to cause errors.

```vb
Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Err.Clear
    Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If    

Set oMailItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

ActiveDocument.Content.Copy
With oMailItem
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = email1
    .To = frmEmailGen.txtEmail.Text
    .CC = frmEmailGen.txtEmail2.Text & ";" & emailCC
    .BCC = emailBCC
    .Subject = emailSubject & frmEmailGen.txtAddress.Text
    .HTMLBody = ""
    .Display
    
    pdfFile = PDFPath & "\" & UCase(frmEmailGen.txtAddress.Text) & ".pdf"
    
   .Attachments.Add PDFFilePath
            
End With

Dim mailWord As Object
Set mailWord = oMailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor
mailWord.Range(0).PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting) '<- ERROR on this line
```

It shows

> error 5097, Word Has Encountered a Problem.

It doesn't like pasting the template to Outlook using the original formatting. I replaced the code with `.Paste` and it works.

A breakpoint on that part, will let the code paste the template to Outlook.
Based on that, a lot of people say that could be a timing issue and the code is running before the program can respond, so add a delay. I tried both `Application.Wait` & `Sleep`.

Since the template is still in my clipboard, I tried ignoring the error (`On Error Resume Next`), pasting the template by CTRL+V, and it works, albeit it's using the formatting of Outlook instead.
The paste options shows up, and when selecting Use Source Formatting, the template is correct now.

I should be able to set the default Paste option to keep the Source Formatting, but that doesn't work. Outlook always uses a new option "Use Destination Theme" which isn't an option on the default actions for Pasting. The only options are Keep Source, Merge Formatting, and Keep Text Only. All the options are set to "Keep Source Formatting".

I already suspect this might be a program issue if it allows me to paste through the email via text, but not the original format of the template.

Before I ask IT to perform repairs on the Office Installation, are there other ways to paste the template to Outlook?

---

IT just finished doing an Online Repair but that didn't fix the issue.

Another behavior: When I make a loop that will try to paste the content again if there's an error, it gets pasted OK as soon as I manually click on the Outlook mail window and the loop gets cut off.
I tried different ways to code this but it only works when I click on it.

Comment: Is Word running at the moment when the code is executed?

Comment: Yes, Word is running alongside a userform (frmEmailGen) where I input some data which is used to customize the template. The code above is a function that is just called once all the information is available so it can start sending the template onto an email.

Comment: Have you tried running your VBA macro from any other Office application when Word is not running? Does it work correctly?

Comment: Yes, my Excel has Personal.XLSB and all the codes within it works as expected.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is related to a case when the `WordEditor` property is used inside the Word application. Have you tried using different parameters with Paste-related methods? Is there any difference?

Comment: Replacing wdFormatOriginalFormatting results in the same errors, but for some reason, just replacing the entire code with .Paste instead of .PasteAndFormat works, but the formatting from the Word is not copied to the mail window, which is not ideal. My current workaround is to simply ignore the error, and as soon as the code is done, I right click on the mail window and paste, Keep Source Formatting and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting`

I found that this line of code caused my macro to crash, all of a sudden, without any particular reason that I can find. Maybe a Microsoft update?

Anyway I found that I could use F8 to step thru the code and it would work correctly.

To resolve the problem,  directly before that code line I inserted a pause using an InputBox.

`MyValue = InputBox("Press Any Key", "Pause" )`

The macros work correctly now.

Comment: Interesting workaround - that actually worked for me as well. Seeing as you're experiencing the same problem, I assume MS did really do something about this. I'm on Office 365 so we're getting constant updates.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Office installation could be corrupted. I'd suggest repairing applications on your machine first to exclude such factors.

The problematic line of code contains multiple property and methods calls:

```
mailWord.Range(0).PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting) '<- ERROR on this line
```

I'd suggest breaking the chain of calls by declaring each property or method call on a separate line of code. Following that way you will be able to find the exact property or method which throws an error at runtime.

Comment: I went to the IT team just now and they finished an Online Repair but it still fails to work.
When you mean breaking the chain of calls, do you mean something like declare one variable as GetInspector, then declare the next variable as the WordEditor after that? I tried to do this but it still fails on the PasteAndFormat section.
I tried other ways like PasteSpecial but same issue..

Comment: Yes, to find the problem you need to call each property or method separately so you could check the results. Are your applications run under different security contexts?

Comment: The codes goes through up until that particular line, despite declaring each property individually. The only method that works is the code: mailWord.Range(0).Paste. This just pastes it directly to the mail window but without the formatting that's on the Word document.

As for security, I made sure to even allow all macros to run (not a good idea in the long run), and also added trusted locations for where my files are.

Comment: That can be related to Outlook security settings. Outlook may trigger security issues/prompts when automated from an external applications.